# Display loading screen immediately after button press and before AJAX call is fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to display the loading element displayed immediately after the button press and before the AJAX call is made.

Here is my code and what I have tried:-

**This code is inside my "on button click" function**

```
$('.loading-container').fadeIn(0);
$('.loading-container').show();
$('.loading-container').css('display', 'block');

console.log("start");

setTimeout(function () {
    getResults();
    console.log("end");
}, 3600);
```

I have tried the `beforeSend` as well but it does not display the loading screen immediately after the button click.

The problem is that loading screen shows 4 or 5 seconds after the button click. How can I make it show immediately after the button click?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async` `await`, here is the reference: [MDN - async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)  or you can use promises which are basically the same [(MDN - Promises)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).